# How to fix PHP errors while trying to create a login.php that displays username at a new page on successful login?

Tags: php, html, database, ms-access, authentication

I am a business student, inexperienced with php,html etc. and as part of a course we were asked to develop a website using HTML,CSS and PHP that has a registration and login page, connected to an MS Access Database. When I first did the login.php page it was a success, but then we were asked to connect it to our homepage and have a welcome message with the Loggedin username. I tried following online suggestions on how do it but I am getting "undefined index error" and "trying to get property of non-object" errors when running my login.php file.

Here is what I have done:

login.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php session_start(); ?>


<?php   
$email=$_GET['email'];
$password=$_GET['password'];


$odbc = odbc_connect ('group7', 'root', '') or die( "Could Not Connect to ODBC Database!");
    $query = odbc_exec($odbc, "SELECT  email, username FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'") or die (odbc_errormsg());

 if ($rs->Fields["email"]->value && $rs->Fields["email"]->value == $email)
if ($rs->Fields["password"]->value && $rs->Fields["password"]->value == $password) 
{ 
$_SESSION["email"] = $email; 
$_SESSION["loggedin"]= true;
// Relocate to the logged-in page 
header("Location: homespace-4 copy/index.php"); 
} 
else 
{ 
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;
$_SESSION["message"] = "login Error as $email." ; 
 } 


    odbc_close($odbc);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Before i put the session_start(); it worked perfectly fine on its own, but was told I needed it for displaying the username on the redirected page. Please help me figure out how to make it work.

Comment: First, you need to start the session before you output any of the HTML.

Comment: It looks like something got misplaced while you were updating it. You're using an `$rs` variable that hasn't been defined beforehand, and you have a `$query` variable that isn't used after it's defined. I think either something is missing that gets `$rs` from `$query`, or `$rs` is actually supposed to be `$query`. I don't have much experience with the odbc functions, so not sure which it is.

Answer (score 0):

These are the things that jump out at me.

1. You cannot use `header("Location: homespace-4 copy/index.php");` unless there has not been any html/header data before it. It just isn't meant to work that way. You have to call it before any html.
2. Avoid putting PHP inside your HTML. Instead, put HTML inside your PHP. *[note: Based on what I see of your code, all of the HTML is unnecessary because you are redirecting your site visitor to your `homespace-4` page.]*
3. Avoid using `$_GET`, it opens you to security risks. Use `$_POST`. Unless, in this instance, your instructor explicitly told you to do it this way.
4. `session_start();` is essentially called for 3 reasons: to add, read, or delete data
5. Putting `session_start();` near the top of your code is "okay", but it is probably better putting in the area you need it to be in. In this case, right above your "if" statement comparing input values. You want it there because you are adding the data (true or false) at that part. *[note: Additional sets of `()` were added to the "if" statement. Please take the time to study them so you understand why they are there.]*

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   if ( (($rs->Fields["email"]->value) && ($rs->Fields["email"]->value == $email)) && ($rs->Fields["password"]->value) && ($rs->Fields["password"]->value == $password)) ) { 
       $_SESSION["email"] = $email; 
       $_SESSION["loggedin"]= true;
       // Relocate to the logged-in page 
       header("Location: homespace-4 copy/index.php"); 
   } else { 
       $_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;
       $_SESSION["message"] = "login Error as $email." ; 
   }
   ?>
   ```

I'm hoping this will give you enough to work with so that you understand the assignment better. Good luck with your class!